# JSF addvaluechangeListener not executed when value changed for dynamically created selectonemenu

Tags: dynamic, jsf-2, primefaces, runtime

I am trying to add a valuechange Listener to dynamically created selectonemenu.Below is the code:

```
SelectOneMenu selectmsgtype = new SelectOneMenu();
UISelectItems msgtypeitems = new UISelectItems();
final String selecttypeBinding = "#{bean.selectmsgtypehash.key"
            + compCount + "}";
final ValueExpression selecttypeValueExp = FacesContext
            .getCurrentInstance()
            .getApplication()
            .getExpressionFactory()
            .createValueExpression(getELContext(), selecttypeBinding,
                    Integer.class);
selectmsgtype.setValueExpression("value", selecttypeValueExp);
selectmsgtype.addValueChangeListener(valueChangeListener);
selectmsgtype.setImmediate(true);
selectmsgtype.getChildren().add(msgtypeitems);
component.getChildren().add(selectmsgtype);*
```

Here `valueChangeListener` is a managedproperty

```
public class CustomValueChangeEvent implements ValueChangeListener  {

@Override
public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent arg0)
        throws AbortProcessingException {
    SelectOneMenu component1=(SelectOneMenu) arg0.getComponent();
    System.out.println("Valuechange"+component1+"\nId"+component1.getId());
//  component1.getId();

    }
}
```

Can anyone let me know what is missing in the above so that the valuechange listener gets executed on change of value?
I am using jsf 2.0 and primefaces

Answer (score 1):

Could be either or both of two things:

1. **You're not setting an `id` for the dynamically created component**: I don't see where you're setting the `id` attribute for the dynamically created component. You need to do this by yourself (JSF won't do it for you because you've taken control of the component creation)

   ```
   selectmsgtype.setId(`theId`);
   ```
2. **How you're calling the listener**: Typically, a `valueChangeListener` runs only when a full (non-ajax) request is sent to the server. You're not showing where (or if) you're firing the request.

---

EDIT: 
Based on your comments, you don't need a `ValueChangeListener`, you need a plain ajax listener. Attach an ajax listener to your dynamically created component using the snippet below:

```
AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior = (AjaxBehavior) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
ajaxBehavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new CustomAjaxListener());
ajaxBehavior.setTransient(true);
selectmsgtype.addClientBehavior("change",ajaxBehavior);
```

`CustomAjaxListener` is going to be an implementation of `AjaxBehaviorListener`:

```
public class CustomAjaxListener implements AjaxBehaviorListener {

@Override
public void processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
   SelectOneMenu component1=(SelectOneMenu) event.getComponent();
   System.out.println("Valuechange"+component1+"\nId"+component1.getId());
  }
}
```

Comment: For Point 1:
I am generating the ID's . Sorry i could not place it here.
    selectmsgtype.setId("selecttype" + compCount + "s");
where compCount is a sequence generated.
For Point 2:Ya you are correct.The valuechangelistener is getting triggerd only when the page is submitted.Can you please let me know how can we make it to trigger when the value is changed?

Comment: @user3094040 - is there any reason why you chose a `valueChangeListener` over an ajax listener? Usually the reason people use the `valueChangeListener` is to be able to get hold of the old and new values of the component. From your code, it doesn't appear you're interested in that. In that case, I'll recommend an ajax listener instead of a `valueChangeListener`. Is that ok?

Comment: The reason I want to use valuechangelistener is ,whenever the value from selectone menu is changed a set of operations needs to be performed using the new value. In my case i need to enable/disable a inputtext box based on the value being selected. Can you help me over this, need to fix it asap?

Comment: I tried the above too.. no luck still... the event is not fired when value changed